# "Average" line over irregular log series data

Tags: time-series, data-visualization, mean, lognormal-distribution

I have simulation data from 1000 runs, plotting some measurable (in this case convergence of the algorithm) as a function of simulation time. Each run produces a discrete set of points `(t, f(t))` and the superimposed image of all the runs looks like:

[image]

Clearly there is some structure here. How can I generate a curve that somehow captures the average value of f(t) for a given t? In addition I'd like to be able to estimate the spread as well, though I'm not sure what the underlying distribution is.

Let's say that this plot was generated from simulation parameters **A**. The goal of this project is to show that another set of simulation parameters **B**, produces a different set of curves, and have a nice way to visualize this.

Comment: In this particular example there is no need for an average line, the semi-transparent traces are quite informative. Simply plot the traces for the different parameter estimates as separate colors. For similar examples see [Hsiang (2013)](http://ssrn.com/abstract=2265501) or [Lofgren (2013)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3415573/).

Comment: @AndyW Perhaps in this picture there is no need to project the data onto a single line, however, I have three reasons why I'd like to know how to do so. 1] I have many parameter sets to compare **A**,**B**,**C**, etc..., 2] I'd like to apply some qualitative analysis to the different "average" curves and I think a projection might be the best place to start. 3] This can't be a unique problem, I think I'd learn something from other approaches.

Comment: @AndyW Thank you for the refs though, the first one looks like something I'd be willing to implement. I'm not sure what to take from the second one however.

Comment: A simple non-parametric approach would be for each `t` just calculate the median, and then plot that median trace. For error intervals you could similarly calculate specific quantiles for each `t` and use those as estimates of the error. Other ways may just use the mean at each `t` point and the standard error of that mean, or try to approximate `f(t)` through some flexible function (e.g. using regresssion with splines for t).

Comment: @AndyW The t values for each function are distinct, in my case they represent a switching time. I'm guessing I could simply bin them on the log scale and apply the median calculation the same way?

Comment: Yes you could bin them and calculate the quantiles of interest (from your question I thought `t` was fixed). The regression approach would work without binning. The bins don't have to be equal (sometimes people makes the bins so they have a minimum number of samples), but in this example it looks like that would not be necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be addressed by using a GAM to model $f(t)$ ~ $t$, and plotting the fitted response curve with its confidence intervals.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Being unfamiliar with GAMs, what does the `~` mean in the equation? $f(t)$ is similar to $t$?

Comment: @Hooked Sorry, that's how R says 'is a function of' i.e. y ~ x reads as 'y is a function of x'. That's not specific to GAMs, it's just how you would tell R the dependent and independent variables.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to accept this as it seems like it will work but if you could provide a starting point or reference to get started I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Hooked Happy to help! They are pretty easy to work with, here's a couple of tutorials to get you started: http://environmentalcomputing.net/intro-to-gams/ & https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2015/07/30/gam/